# How to execute a JanusGraph jar file?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I managed to build a jar file named "" following this official "[Connecting from Java](https://docs.janusgraph.org/connecting/java/)" tutorial. 
**How can I execute this jar file?**

> Say I have a HBase jar file, I may execute it in the console by `hbase com.HbaseExample` or `hadoop com.HbaseExample`.

What is the magical line to execute a JanusGraph jar? I have attached the example codes below:

```
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.empty.EmptyGraph;


public class executeGremlin {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Graph graph = (Graph) EmptyGraph.instance();
        GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal().withRemote("conf/remote-graph.properties");
        Object herculesAge = g.V().has("name", "hercules").values("age").next();
        System.out.println("Hercules is " + herculesAge + " years old.");
    }
}
```

And the jar file is named gremlin-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is expecting to connect to a Gremlin Server. The Server would have to be configured to use JanusGraph. Note that JanusGraph needs a process to launch it (such as your application or a Gremlin Server) and also some backend storage unless you configure it to run as "inmemory". I have a section on setting up JanusGraph in Practical Gremlin. I wrote that section a while back but I think it still should be mostly correct.Definitely check with the official docs also.

http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#janusintro

There is some sample Java code here that goes along with the examples in the book.

https://github.com/krlawrence/graph/blob/master/sample-code/JanusCassandra.java